# Iterate from one method and call next element in the loop from another method - ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The code is as follows

```
params.each do |settings|
          update(settings)
        end

def update(settings)
      selected_feature = ADMIN_FEATURES.detect { |feature| feature[:name] == settings[:name] }
      next unless selected_feature
      if selected_feature[:inherited]
        company.subtree.each { |co| set_company_configuration(co) }
      else
        set_company_configuration(company)
      end
end
```

If selected feature is not found, it should iterate on the next element. Any idea on how to get this to work?

Comment: `return unless selected_feature`

Comment: that will break the loop right? i need to iterate the next element.

Comment: Did you try it? Next element from params, right?

Comment: yes, next element from params

Comment: `return` will not break the loop in above case. it will return to the method from which called and continue with next iteration.

Comment: `return if selected_feature.nil?` might read a tad better.